# function setState in flutter is not updating variable

Tags: flutter, forms, dart

Okay so I have a page where according to button pressed beforehand a group of slides is shown. If the group of slides is not unlocked yet, instead, one slide with TextFormField will appear. If a code i written into it it will check if its in a database. The only thing I need is, that when the code is not in the database, the border of the TextFormField should turn red.

Problem is, the setState() is not updating the border conditions. I tested it out, the variable is updated, but the page is not rebuilded.

Here's the code of the code page:

```
class _BreathingSlidesState extends State<BreathingSlides> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  late List<Widget> slideContent;
  List<String> premium = ['Inhalation', 'Procedures'];
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController _textFieldController = TextEditingController();
  bool? goodCode;

  void updateDoneValue(bool value) {
    final breathingWidget = context.findAncestorStateOfType<_BreathingState>();
    if (breathingWidget != null) {
      setState(() {
        widget.updateDone(value);
      });
    }
  }

  void dispose() {
    _textFieldController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<bool> fetchData(String value) async {
    List<String> dataList = [];

    final querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('uCodes').get();

    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
      var fieldValue = doc.data()['1'].toString();
      dataList.add(fieldValue);
    });

    return dataList.contains(value);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if(premium.contains(widget.buttonContext))
    {
      slideContent = [
        Column(
          children: [
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 80.0, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20),
              child: Align(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text("You haven't unlocked this lesson yet",textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
            ),
            Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 60, vertical: 20),
                    child: Builder(
                      builder: (context) {
                        return TextFormField(
                          controller: _textFieldController,
                          onFieldSubmitted: (value) async {
                            _textFieldController.clear();
                            if (await fetchData(value)) {
                              goodCode = true;
                              setState(() {
                                print("jj");
                                goodCode = true;  
                              });
                            }
                            else{
                              goodCode = false;
                              setState(() {
                                print("nn");
                                goodCode = false; // Set the flag to false if a bad input is detected
                              });
                            print(goodCode);
                            }
                          },
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: goodCode == null ? Colors.grey : Colors.red, // Set border color based on validation result
                                width: 2, // Set border width
                              ),
                            ),
                            label: const Center(child: Text("Enter your uCode"),),
                            floatingLabelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 78, 125, 79), fontSize: 20),
                            focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 115, 171, 117), width: 4)
                            )
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    ),
                  ),
                ]
              )
              //odkaz do shopu
            ),
        ])];
    }
```

Here the slides are applied:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 78, 125, 79),
            title: const Text('x XP', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25)),
            centerTitle: true
          ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: PageView.builder(
              itemCount: slideContent.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Center(
                  child: slideContent[index],
                );
              },
              onPageChanged: (index) {
                setState(() {
                  _currentIndex = index;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              for (int i = 0; i < slideContent.length; i++)
                _buildDot(i == _currentIndex),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Any ideas are appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: I think the problem is your _formKey, try comment out those lines and check if without _formKey, it setState successfully

Comment: No that didn't help, thanks for the suggestion tho. Why would _formKey block it?

Answer (score 1):

Okay so for anyone wondering, after some hardcore debugging xd i found that setState() is indeed called properly, but it's not updated to the Center widget in PageView.builder.
I couldn't find how to pass the variables to the widget, but i learned about StatefulBuilder(). It updates only the widgets in it, and that helped.
I am now wondering tho if there's something like this, but without widgets, only with code.
Good luck with coding!